# Transpile es6 to es5 in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am seeing a lot of people/tutorial are transpiling es6 to es5 using babel when developing with node.js and express.

My question is: What are the benefits of this and why it should be done?

I am deploying the node.js REST api into server and I do not see any benefits of transpiling to es5 here.

Comment: There are no *benefits*, you just have to do that if the target runtime does not support features you're using in your code.

Comment: @zerkms what do you mean by target runtime here

Comment: `nodejs` is a runtime. If you distribute your app to the clients that run it on the ancient versions of nodejs - you must do that. Otherwise, don't.

Comment: Some deployment/production environments may be stuck back on node.js 4.x.

Comment: Nodejs supports es6 natively, so transpling es6 to es5 for node is no benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no benefits which I am aware of. Transpiling is usually done because the runtime will not support the feature/language/framework you are using to develop.

For example, if your runtime (node) has not been upgraded to v6 or above, then es6 is not supported. If you wanted to develop in es6 anyway, you'd need a transpiler like babel.

More commonly, es6 transpilers would be used for client side code. since ie supports very little / no es6 https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/